# Двумерные массивы в ассемблере

Tags: c, массивы, ассемблер

Не понимаю как использовать двумерные массивы на ассемблере. Вот пример кода, как сделать такое же с двумерным массивом?

```
void main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
int A[5], i = 0, max = A[0];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("A[%d] = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (A[i] > max) {
        max = A[i];
    }
}
printf("max on c = %d\n", max);
max = 0;
__asm {
    cld
    mov ecx, 5 // ЕСХ = всего элементов
    lea esi, A // ESI = адрес массива
    mov ebx, [esi] // EBX = первый элемент
lp: lodsd // ЕАХ = очередной элемент массива
    cmp eax, ebx
    jbe bol // переход, если меньше
    mov ebx, eax //присваиваем макс значение
bol: Loop  lp // промотать ЕСХ - раз..
    mov max, ebx
}
printf("max on asm = %d\n", max);
getch();
```

}

Comment: Если ваш массив будет примерно таким: `int A[5][6]`, то его структура в памяти будет линейной. Сначала будут 6 элементов первой строки, затем шесть элементов второй строки и так далее. Соответственно, к элементу `A[n][m]` можно обратиться по адресу `A+5*n+m`. Если же массив примерно такой: `int **A`, то всё сложнее.

Comment: А зачем вам для этого ассемблер? Код, написанный на `c` очень хорошо транслируется в ассемблер. Вряд ли вы напишите на ассемблере код лучше, чем компилятор с оптимизацией. Как вариант - напишите код на С, добавьте ключ к опциям компилятора и он сгенерит ассемблерные файлы (для GCC -S). Или скопируйте кусок кода в CompilerExplorer и посмотрите как он выглядит в ассемблере.